# The tag [devtools] needs to be more developed

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, retag-request

The tag [devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devtools) is ambiguous. Officially, it's supposed to be used for the R package:

> An R package containing tools to ease the task of software development.

But lots of questions are about other "dev tools". For example, ["[devtools] chrome"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdevtools%5D+chrome) gets 122 matches, but that should use [google-chrome-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools) (4,273 questions).

The questions relating to "R" should be moved to a new tag, perhaps [r-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-devtools), and the questions relating to Google devtools should be moved to [google-chrome-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools). If there's any other questions, they can be dealt with as appropriate.

Comment: And what should happen to the [tag:devtools] then? You want to burninate it? Cause it's not very clear from your question